# how to disable all the button using an on_off button in javafx?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

[image]

it is a simple calculator made by using `javaFx`. My problem is that i want to use the on_off button to get power and to get inactive the calculator. How to do so??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your buttons in some container where you can iterate through them and set the onAction of your of off to `setDisable(true)` on them?

Comment: got the solution for my problem. thanks all for your kind suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using SceneBuilder alone, however it could be done by editing the fxml yourself. Just use a `ToggleButton` for the on/off button and bind the `disable` properties to the `selected` property of the `ToggleButton` or do this in the `initialize` method of the controller (requires all `Button`s to be injected to the controller via `fx:id`).

#### binding in fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" spacing="10">
    <padding>
        <Insets left="10" right="10" bottom="10" top="10" />
    </padding>
    <children>
        <fx:define>
            <!-- create ToggleButton to be used with the disable properties -->
            <ToggleButton fx:id="on" text="On"/>
        </fx:define>
        <!-- create buttons and bind the disable property to the negated 
             selected property of the on button -->
        <Button text="Button 1" disable="${!on.selected}" />
        <Button text="Button 2" disable="${!on.selected}" />
        <Button text="Button 3" disable="${!on.selected}" />
        <Button text="Button 4" disable="${!on.selected}" />
        <Button text="Button 5" disable="${!on.selected}" />
        <!-- add on button to scene -->
        <fx:reference source="on"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

#### binding in controller

```
@FXML
private Button button1;

@FXML
private Button button2;

@FXML
private Button button3;
...

@FXML
private ToggleButton on;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    BooleanBinding disable = on.selectedProperty().not();
    button1.disableProperty().bind(disable);
    button2.disableProperty().bind(disable);
    button3.disableProperty().bind(disable);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make this quickly i advice you to add all buttons, except for the on/off one to a container like an hbox v box or what you want, then to disable the container(parent) which contains your buttons e.g.

```
vBoxMain.getChildren().addAll(/*every button except on/off*/);
//or generate dynamically the buttons and add them to the vBoxMain in a for cycle
buttonOnOff.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {

    if(vBoxMain.isDidable()){
        vBoxMain.setDisable(false);
    }else{
        vBoxMain.setDisable(true);
    }

});
```

This is not for your specific layout but to give you an idea, i hope it would be helpful to you.